# Can't get an Id passed via URL in a Controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

How can I pass an `id` in the URL and use it in my controller?

*What I'm Trying*:

```
{
   "data": "id",
   render: function(data, type, row) {
      return `<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-circle"><a href="Invoice/"{id}><i class="fa fa-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></button>`;
   }
}
```

*Expected result:*

Click on the button and be directed to a specific URL `id`.

Answer (score 3):

Add a route in `routes/web.php`

```
Route::get('invoice/{id}', 'InvoiceController@invoice');
```

And change the code as

```
{"data" : "id",
  render : function(data, type, row){
    return `<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-circle"><a href="{{ route('invoice', ['id' => id]) }}"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></button>`;
  }
}
```

Reference [here](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing)

Answer (score 2):

You can update your render function with [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) like this:

```
render: function(data, type, row) {
   return 
   `<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-circle">
        <a href="Invoice/${id}"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </button>`;
}
```

Demo using template literals:

```js
let id = 5;
console.log(`Id here is ${id}`)
```